# Apache SOLR import from MySQL DB

Tags: mysql, solr

Within schema.xml of Apache SOLR, what do the different SQL data types map into, specifically blob, tinytext, and varchar.

I followed http://wiki.apache.org/solr/DIHQuickStart, http://entropytc.com/importing-a-mysql-database-into-apache-solr/#codesyntax_1, and http://www.beingjavaguys.com/2013/01/how-to-use-solr-data-import-handler-to.html, inserted my code into the example configuration as suggested to, and fixed the could not find DataImportHandler error.

I have each field in the database table given its own field tag with indexing set to true and its data type.

Whenever I run the import, I only get a message that says, "Indexing failed. Rolled back all changes." What are other possible sources of this problem?

Comment: Any errors should be logged to your Solr log, as long as you have configured SolrLogging and set an appropriate log level. You can apply row logging to DIH as well.

Comment: Thank you. Looking through the log allowed me to find what the problem really was.

Answer (score 0):

Any errors should be logged to your Solr log, as long as you have [configured SolrLogging](https://wiki.apache.org/solr/SolrLogging) and set an appropriate log level. You can [apply row logging to DIH](http://wiki.apache.org/solr/DataImportHandler#LogTransformer) as well.